# Why do I get a white screen when I use my cURL with a proxy?

Tags: php, curl, proxy

Why isn't my cURL working with a proxy? I have tried using several proxies and it all it ever does is give me a white screen.

Here is the PHP code:

```
function curl($url){ // Defining the basic cURL function
    $proxy = '122.166.5.84:8080';

    $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxy_userpass);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if($data === false || curl_error($ch)) {
        return $data;
    }else{
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: As with all white screens of death: enable error reporting and find it out yourself

Comment: I have enabled error_reporting(E_ALL); and nothing still appears.

Comment: Have you also enabled display errors?

Comment: Yeah, I have a .htaccess with 'ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
'.

Comment: `if($data === false || curl_error($ch)) {return $data;}` Assuming you're echoing from this function, echoing `false` displays nothing.